# How to make request from JavaScript by analogy curl request

Tags: javascript, curl, fetch, isomorphic

I need make request from JavaScript, but I only know how to make it with `curl`:

```
curl https://example.com/api -u test_123: -d source=123 -d description="Aaaa Bbbb" -d email="aaaa@example.com"
```

I know that `-d` is a POST parameter, so I can make:

```
fetch(`${config.baseUrl}/api/users/profile/`,
{ method: 'POST',
  data: JSON.stringify({source: 123, description: 'Aaaa Bbb', email: 'aaaa@example.com'})
})
.then(response => {
  // do something
})
```

How can I set `-u` user? Is it a header?

**Update**

I've made a request in debug mode and get the following output:

```
> * Server auth using Basic with user 'sk_test_GAaENEsG0PBmvtHBA2g49sPy'
> > POST /v1/customers HTTP/1.1
> > Authorization: Basic c2tfdGVzdF9HQWFFTkVzRzBQQm12dEhCQTJnNDlzUHk6
> > User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> > Host: api.stripe.com
> > Accept: */*
> > Content-Length: 94
> > Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

So the `-u` option just converts to base64?

Comment: Not sure how to do it with isomorphic, but you might want to check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31473420/make-an-http-post-authentication-basic-request-using-javascript

Comment: Em, there is not answer.. )

Comment: Aaa ok I've got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know this `fetch` function you're using, and I'm assuming it's part of isomorphic. If its supports a `headers` option you can set the `Authorization` header with a base64 encoded token:

```
fetch(`${config.baseUrl}/api/users/profile/`,
{ method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    "Authorization": "Basic " + window.btoa("test_123:password")
  },
  data: JSON.stringify({source: 123, description: 'Aaaa Bbb', email: 'aaaa@example.com'})
})
.then(response => {
  // do something
})
```