# Create checkout session NBG

Tags: javascript, payment-gateway, basic-authentication, cs-cart

I would like to make a Basic HTTP authentication call request via javascript but I do not know how to do it.. I have a javascript code and inside of it there is a session parameter. Thus, I need to make first this call, get the session_id from this call as a response and continue my javascript code. This is the doc of this basic http auth: https://ibanke-commerce.nbg.gr/api/documentation/apiDocumentation/rest-json/version/latest/operation/Session%3a%20Create%20Checkout%20Session.html?locale=en_US

It is about payment option between bank and ecommerce.

How will this be written in javascript?
My code structure is like this for now:

```
<script
//need call auth somewhere here I guess

Payment.Config({
... ... ..
Url: "...",
Name: "...",
session: "here I need the response of the call"
...
...
});
</script>
```

Any help/guidelines would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need three things:

**1. Create you Basic Header for your authentication**

The Basic Header is an Base64 encoded string of your user and
    password. To get that you should encode your credentials as shown below.

```
user_id:password
```

In you case `user_id` is the `merchantId`

You can use online services like [this](https://www.base64encode.org/) to encode your credentials strings

Or

You can encode it in your javascript code like this

```
var clientId = "user_id";
var clientSecret = "password";

// var authorizationBasic = $.base64.btoa(clientId + ':' + clientSecret); // jQuery
var authorizationBasic = window.btoa(clientId + ':' + clientSecret); // Javascript
```

I would recommend the first option.

**2. Make your post request with the Basic Header**

You can follow this answer on how to [make an HTTP POST authentication basic request using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31477937)

**3. Use the response from the authentication request in your code**

So your final code would be something like this

```
var url = 'your_url_server';
var authorizationBasic = 'the_created_basic_header';

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', url, true);
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + authorizationBasic);
request.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json'); // Modify according to the response format
request.send("parameter1=parameter1_value&parameter2=parameter2_value"); // Any parameter you might need

request.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (request.readyState === 4) {
       alert(request.responseText);
       Payment.Config({
          ... ... ..
          Url: "...",
          Name: "...",
          session: request.responseText // Here is the response of the call
          ...
          ...
       });
    }
};
```

Comment: very helpful, detailed answer
I will give it a try!